# Composer class not found

Tags: composer-php, autoload

I have this folder structure that I composerized:

`|--repo-name
  |---lib
    |--TalentLMS
    |--TalentLMS.php`

My autoload is this

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
       "TalentLMS\\": "lib/"
    }
}
```

When I tried calling the TalentLMS class, I always get `Class 'TalentLMS' not found`.

I tried removing the trailing slash in `lib` in the composer.json but still no joy.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem.

All I did was reorganized the structure and added proper namespacing.

Comment: Could you please add more details to your answer